# List prints multiple times instead of once

Tags: python, list

Hello I have a code here.

```py
datasets = []
datasets.append([14.2, 32.5, 42.1, 74.5, 43.5])
datasets.append([25.7, 34.1, 48.7, 50.3])
datasets.append([11.2, 26.9, 95.1, 52.1, 23.5, 5.6, 45.7, 37.8])
datasets.append([54.7, 25.3])
    
# Function
def summary_function(datasets):
    for k in datasets:
        summary_value = min(datasets)/len(datasets)
    return summary_value
    
# Create Summary List
summary_list = []
for i in range(len(datasets)):
    summary_value = summary_function(datasets[i])
    summary_list.append(summary_value)
    print('Summary List:',summary_list)
```

This code prints the list like this:

```
Summary List: [2.84]
Summary List: [2.84, 6.425]
Summary List: [2.84, 6.425, 0.7]
Summary List: [2.84, 6.425, 0.7, 12.65]
```

How do I make the print output to look like this:

```
Summary List: [2.84, 6.425, 0.7, 12.65]
```

Comment: Could you just take `print('Summary List:',summary_list)` out of the loop by deindenting it i.e. removing spaces from the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code

```py
datasets = []
datasets.append([14.2, 32.5, 42.1, 74.5, 43.5])
datasets.append([25.7, 34.1, 48.7, 50.3])
datasets.append([11.2, 26.9, 95.1, 52.1, 23.5, 5.6, 45.7, 37.8])
datasets.append([54.7, 25.3])

# Function
def summary_function(datasets):
    for k in datasets:
        summary_value = min(datasets)/len(datasets)
    return summary_value

# Create Summary List
summary_list = []
for i in range(len(datasets)):
    summary_value = summary_function(datasets[i])
    summary_list.append(summary_value)
print('Summary List:',summary_list) # no longer in the for loop
```

If you move the last line `print('Summary List:',summary_list)` to be outside of the loop it will only print after the loop has finished and not while it is iterating.

#### Output

```py
Summary List: [2.84, 6.425, 0.7, 12.65]
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was an easy fix. Thank you Jacques :D I'm still learning python haha

Comment: @WillsonAndreasBlesstian No problem glad I could help! Could you mark this question as correct?

Comment: Yup, just did. Thank you :D